# R function won't save data to global environment

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function that uses the Pushshift API to get data from subreddits, and iterates over the function to get more than the maximum amount of posts. So far it works and prints to the screen, but won't save the data frame to the environment. What am I doing wrong here? Bit of an R newbie so any help and explanations would be great!

Here is my code:

```
get_data_loop <- function(after, subreddit, iterations = c(1:2)) {
    
  loopeddata <- as.data.frame(NULL)
    
  for(i in iterations) {
    
    after+1
    
  data <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?after=", after, "d&subreddit=", subreddit, "&size=100&fields=body,author", sep = "")))

    loopeddata <- rbind(data, loopeddata)
    
    #Sleep for API 
    
  Sys.sleep(5)

  }
  
  
print(i)

view(loopeddata)

}
```

Comment: your function is missing a `return()` function

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return` the variable you are interested in from the function. In the last line of your function use `return(loopeddata)` and then run the function as

```r
loopeddata <- get_data_loop(..your..options..)
```

Alternatively, you can, after the iterations, assign that variable from inside the function to a global variable. Last functon line could be but I would prefer the former soltuon which is cleaner:

```r
assign("loopeddata", loopeddata, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot. Quite clear what I did wrong here too - newbie mistake!